# Don't Post WIP?

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer, and found some bugs, so I removed a lot of the code and replaced it with a generic "#TODO: ..." in the grace period.

Was then deleted by doorknob.

So when is it now ok to have a "WIP" answer?

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to mention that the entirety of your answer was:

> ### Tcl (WIP)
>
> ```
> if {[llength $argv] != 3} {
>     puts stderr "Usage $argv0 prob mut periods"
>     exit 1
> }
> # TODO... implement this stuff
> ```
>
> Satisfies by now only the
>
> > The user must input three variables using argv
>
> rule.
>
> Should produce the correct result for your test.

I'm not sure this even qualifies as a W, much less a WIP. That has absolutely nothing to do with the challenge. Please elaborate on how you think this is an answer, because I'm not seeing it.

It's debatable whether WIP answers are okay, but (I hope!) we can all agree that `txt = input(); #TODO` is far from a proper answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you realise that your answer is completely borked and you need to start from scratch, delete the answer yourself. Then once you've fixed it you can edit and undelete. There's no benefit to anyone to keep an "answer" which doesn't do anything except validate the number of arguments.

Comment: And now there are 2 answers for people over 3k...

Comment: Yeah, deletion would be better, but I'd like to keep the algorithm a trade secret until I posted a valid answer.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn How does not deleting help with that?

Comment: Haven't thought of it, but a mod deletion just turns that thing into data junk. Ideal flow: Remove code, delete myself, fix it, edit undelete. Now: Remove code, deleted by mod, can't undelete.

Comment: You could have asked me to delete, but someone is trigger happy.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I think Doorknob is doing a great job deleting low-quality posts on this site. Sure, he may delete more posts than necessary, but I would rather he do that than for him to miss others. And you say, "You could have asked me to delete". I believe that mods can undelete mod-deleted posts, and it seems as if I can vote to undelete too. You could have asked Doorknob to reverse it.

Comment: If you want to keep a "trade secret", don't post anything until it's done. When you edit out code, it's still visible in the revision history. Forever.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn You can flag your post if you've fixed it and you want it undeleted. It was flagged as "not an answer," and it was indeed not an answer, so I don't see why it should have been kept around any longer.

Comment: @Geobits He managed to edit it out within the 5 minute grace period.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in most cases **WIP** is unnecessary. There's nothing that's going to taken so why reserve a place?

The only reason I could think of that a WIP could be posted would be with a King of the Hill where you want to reserve a really cool name that you thought up.

Finally, with the program you posted, there was *nothing* of use. It may have well been blank. An acceptable WIP would be one that had some relevant code but still had some to go, or one that was complete but you were just bugfixing it.

Comment: Personally, I would downvote a KotH WIP if I thought the only reason it was prematurely posted was to reserve a cool name.